# Elasticsearch multi_query with a static field value

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I've followed [this tutorial](https://madewithlove.be/how-to-integrate-elasticsearch-in-your-laravel-app-2019-edition/) to get Elasticsearch working with Laravel 6. Everything works fine but I need to make few changes to the query. I need to make changes to this:

```php
private function searchOnElasticsearch(string $query = '', int $fooId = 3): array
    {
        $model = new Customer;

        $items = $this->elasticsearch->search([
            'index' => $model->getSearchIndex(),
            'type' => $model->getSearchType(),
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'multi_match' => [
                        'type' => 'best_fields',
                        'fields' => ['FirstName^5', 'Surname^5'],
                        'query' => $query,
                        // I need to include this:
                        // fields ['foo_id' => $fooId]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        return $items;
    }
```

Essentially, this queries the entire model based on the `query`. I dont want that. A user can only return data based on a column's value. Let's say the model is call `Customers`. On the customers table, a field called `foo_id`. I need a similar search like:

```php
Customer::query()
  ->whereRaw("UPPER(field) LIKE '%". strtoupper($query)."%' AND foo_id =" . 3)
```

How can I include a static field value with `multi_match`? I've looked at [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) but nothing seems to work?

Answer (score 0):

In the event someone is looking similar answer:

```php
/** Optional to limit number of results returned:
 * "from" => 0,
 * "size" => 5,
 */
"query" => [
        "bool" => [
            "must" => [
                ["match" => ["foo_id" => 3]], // static value
                [
                    "multi_match" => [
                        "query" => $query,
                        "type" => "cross_fields",
                        "operator" => "or",
                        "fields" => [
                            "FirstName",
                            "Surname",
                            // .. other fields
                        ],
                        "minimum_should_match" => "2",
                    ]
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```